# Doctrine 2: How to handle join tables with extra columns

Tags: properties, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, join

How do I setup a join table with extra columns, or a many-to-many association with additional properties, in Doctrine 2?

Comment: @ThatBlairGuy I noticed you are removing a lot of the [tag:extra] tag.  This edit was adequate, but please be sure to _fix all aspects of a post_ in addition to removing the tag.  For more, read this [meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

First off, let me explain that this does **not** exist:

A *join table* (also known as a *junction table* or *cross-reference table*) is a table that links 2 (or more) other tables together within the same database by primary key.
This means that a join table will only contain foreign keys, there is no place for these extra columns.

So when you need extra columns in such a table, it is no longer just a "link" between other tables, but becomes a *real table* on its own!

In terms of Doctrine 2, you no longer have a many-to-many association between 2 entities, but get a one-to-many/many-to-one association between 3 entities.

Continue reading here for more detailed explanations:

- [Doctrine 2: How to handle join tables with extra columns](https://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/06/doctrine-2-how-to-handle-join-tables-with-extra-columns/)
- [More on one-to-many/many-to-one associations in Doctrine 2](https://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/10/more-on-one-to-manymany-to-one-associations-in-doctrine-2/)

Answer (score 1):

In the second article, I suggest a minor update. Instead of the full event, use a **LifecycleCallback** within the entity itself:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="jobs”)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Job
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove
     */
    public function preRemoveCallback()
    {
        $this->setPerson(null);
        $this->setCompany(null);
    }
}
```