# Symfony2 How to persist ManyToMany using forms and entity type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have three tables `team`, `groups` and `group_team`. `group` has a `oneToMany` with `group_team` and `team` has a `OneToOne` with `group_team`. one group can have many teams, and one team can belong to only one group. here is my database design for it

how do i persist the `oneToMany` relationship of groups and team to a third table while simultaneously createing the `groups` record in the database

[image]

and here is the group entity form type

```
class GroupsType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('team', 'entity', array(
                                        'class' => 'CricketBundle\Model\Entity\Team',
                                        'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
                                                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                                                                      ->groupBy('t.team')
                                                                      ->orderBy('t.team', 'ASC');
                                                            }, 
                                        'choice_label' => 'team',
                                        'multiple'     => true,
                                        'expanded'     => true,
                                        'required' => false
                                    ))
                ->add('groupname')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) { 
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CricketBundle\Model\Entity\Groups'
        ));
    }
}
```

here is how the groups entity form renders

[image][image]

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655286/doctrine-2-how-to-handle-join-tables-with-extra-columns/18655514#18655514

Comment: @craigh yes, that certainly helps, when i posted this question i was under the wrong assumption, it is supposed to be a oneToMany/ManyToOne relationship, the third table must have a seperate entity and form type, then using cascade persist to create the group row and using foreach loop persist the association in the third table. use of `clone` is necessary to tell flush() to insert multiple group_team objects. i have the problem solved, but i dont know what to do with this wrongly asked question.

Comment: You can always edit your question with the proper issue, and then answer it yourself with how you resolved it.