# Many to many relation with attributes in Symfony2 forms

Tags: php, symfony

I have built a many to many relation with attributes between entities. I am quite sure entities are correct but I am struggling with the form.

Here is my db model :

- User
- Skill
- UserSkill (with a rating field)

My goal is to create a User with a form and to be able to add many skill to this user. For each skill, I have to add a rating.

Here is the way I create the form :

```
$builder->add('userSkill', 'collection', array(
  'entry_type'      => new UserSkillType(),
  'by_reference'    => false,
  'allow_add'       => true,
  'allow_delete'    => true,
  'add_button_text' => 'Add a skill'
));
```

And here is the error I get :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user_skill (rating, user_id, skill_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [9, null, 3]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null
```

Do you know any good link which can show me how to do or do you have a working example ?

Thank you

NB : I have already built Many-to-many relation form but it is the first time I do it with attributes.

Comment: For whatever reason your UserSkill entity does not have a reference to the User entity.  You will need to check your code to determine why $userSkill->setUser($user) is not being called.

Comment: You are right. My bad, I made a typo in my code at this very line.

Comment: a good resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655286/doctrine-2-how-to-handle-join-tables-with-extra-columns/18655514#18655514

Comment: @pauletienney Could you share the code of the UserSkillType class with me? That would be very helpful.