# Symfony2: Adding a join condition to a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to change something in an existing Symfony2 project, but unfortunately I have never worked with Symfony2 before.

The database contains the following tables:

```
Location
========
id 
....

Deal
========
id 
deleted
...

deal_location
=================
deal 
location
```

There is a Many-To-Many relationship between Deal and Location. This is mapped in the Location.orm.yml file like this:

```
 manyToMany:
    deals:
        cascade: ['all']
        targetEntity: Deal
        mappedBy: locations
```

What I want to do is to exclude all deals which where deleted (deleted = 1) when reading the locations from the Database.

As I found out, this can be done in de LocationRepository class. In that class, I found the following function:

```
    public function getFindAllByLatLonQueryBuilder($lat, $lon)
{

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');
    $qb
        ->where('l.deleted IS NULL OR l.deleted = false')
        ->orderBy('(((ACOS(SIN((:lat*PI()/180)) *
        SIN((l.latitude*PI()/180))+COS((:lat*PI()/180)) *
        COS((l.latitude*PI()/180)) * COS(((:lon-l.longitude)*
        PI()/180))))*180/PI())*60*1.1515*1.609344)', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter('lat', $lat)
        ->setParameter('lon', $lon)
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711299/doctrine-manytomany-relation-with-join-condition) and added the following line:

```
 ->leftJoin('l.deals', 'deals', 'WITH', 'deals.deleted = 0')
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having two conditions in your `where` clause I would leave only `where('l.deleted IS NOT true AND deals.deleted IS NOT true')` and would simply add the `leftJoin` clause.

Something like this should do the work:

```
public function getFindAllByLatLonQueryBuilder($lat, $lon)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->leftJoin('l.deal', 'deal', 'WITH', 'deal.deleted IS NOT true') // you can also try 'deal.deleted != true'
        ->where('l.deleted IS NOT true')
        ->orderBy('(((ACOS(SIN((:lat*PI()/180)) *
        SIN((l.latitude*PI()/180))+COS((:lat*PI()/180)) *
        COS((l.latitude*PI()/180)) * COS(((:lon-l.longitude)*
        PI()/180))))*180/PI())*60*1.1515*1.609344)', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter('lat', $lat)
        ->setParameter('lon', $lon)
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: I think this would only work if location had only one deal, but location has a list of deals.

Comment: Oops, I forgot you mentioned it's a `Many-to-Many` relationship. I've updated my answer. This should be working - I have a similar relationship and the code above works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
->leftJoin('l.deals', 'deal', 'WITH', 'deal.deleted = 0')
```

you always have to join the object's name which in your case seems to be deals instead of deal given your yml.

Another thing which makes me wonder is why for location they check on deleted = null or false (see your code) but you check against deleted = 0. Are you sure this is the right check?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the missing s was just a typo. And yes, I am sure the check is right. For some reason the original programmer used a boolean in Location, but an Int in Deal.

Comment: typo in your code or type when copying it into this question?

Comment: Typo in the question.

Answer (score -1):

leftJoin() not help u, is only needed if u use data from it in query, it not exclude deals, because u in this query get only localization.
I think exclude localization with deleted deals not help to, because in some localization u will have deleted and not deals. It must be in other part of code where u get deals for localizations.
So u must first find where deals are get from db, to make it only take not deleted.

Comment: So, I explain. This method is in LocalizationRepository, so alias l represent this table, doing _left_ join, u only join deals to localization, make some double, some will not have deal at all, but it not limit localization. Next thing is how doctrine works, even u do join, but not declare in select() u want hydrate table, doctrine will not do it, so u join data, but not get it in result object. So after iterate on localization and do method to get deals, u get all deals, even with this stupid join. Even u hydrate data, u will get all deals, but maybe less query